# What is the equivalent JavaScript regex for this php regex boundary set?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression:

```
(?<=Employee\s)([a-zA-Z ]+?)(?=\s?that)
```

to match every name in between two words.(`Employee` and `that`)

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/76)

but this is written for `php` and I need the `JavaScrpit` *"flavor"*.

If I remove the *"offending"* codes:

```
(Employee\s)([a-zA-Z ]+?)(?=\s?that)
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/82)

Then the regular expression is including also Employee. How can I write the regular expression to exclude the `Employee` word and include only the words between `Employee` and `that` just like in the first `php` regular expression.

Comment: One option is to make `Employee` non-capturing (`?:`) (or no group at all) and extract the 1st group (`match(...)[1]`).

Comment: @georg is there a way without groups?

Comment: No, that would be look-behind, sadly missing in JS regexps. Why does have to be a regexp, and why can't you use groups?

Comment: @torazaburo I am using this for VBA in fact, but VBA is JS compatible. I don't know how to use groups in VBA. Thanks for the info

Comment: If you want to do something that needs groups, then you have to learn how to use them. I don't know VBA but it's highly doubtful it doesn't support groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?:` is a non-capturing group, so just put that before your Employee part of the regex:

```
(?:Employee\s)([a-zA-Z ]+?)(?=\s?that)
```

Here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/83) to test.

---

You can also just take it out of a capture group completely:

```
Employee\s([a-zA-Z ]+?)(?=\s?that)
```

Here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/84) of this version.

Comment: Still includes the Employee in the selection

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu What do you mean by "selection"? How are you calling this regexp, and what are you doing with the results? In order to take advantage of capturing groups, and ignore things which are not part of capturing groups, you need to call it in a way which does that.